# Uninstalling Maven from Mac OSX and windows

Tags: windows, macos, maven, uninstallation

I have already installed Maven 3.3.9 on both Mac OSX and Windows 10.
However I face some issues relating to the local repository.
So, I think that it would be a good idea to uninstall are re install maven.
I am looking for a guide on how to completely remove maven, but I cannot find any.
Can you please help me with that??

Thanks in advance!!! :)

Comment: If you have issue with local repository remove $HOME/.m2/repository and your issue will disappear

Comment: I have another localrepository in my hd. What should I do with it?? @michaldo

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you but: 1. If you have problem with local repository then delete the repository; maven will recreate it. 2. If you have problem with maven, remove maven folder: there is no installer. 3. If you have problem with your maven settings, remove  $HOME/.m2/settings.xml

Comment: @michaldo so I will just delete the local repo (1). In terms of 3 there is no settings.xml file. There is only the repository folder.

Answer (score 16):

```
do  "which mvn"
```

it will give you the path of mvn like this:
`/usr/local/bin/mvn`

```
do cd /usr/local/bin/
do ls -lrt | grep -i mvn
```

It will give you location from where mvn binary is picked up, sth like this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 syaduvanshi  admin    29B Sep  5 16:49 mvn -> ../Cellar/maven/3.6.2/bin/mvn

lrwxr-xr-x  1 syaduvanshi  admin    34B Sep  5 16:49 mvnDebug -> ../Cellar/maven/3.6.2/bin/mvnDebug

lrwxr-xr-x  1 syaduvanshi  admin    32B Sep  5 16:49 mvnyjp -> ../Cellar/maven/3.6.2/bin/mvnyjp
```

Now just go to that location and remove the maven folder

```
cd ../Cellar/

rm -rf maven
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks !!

Comment: I was facing trouble when I wish to downgrade mvn version from 3.6.3 to 3.6.2.2. Even after updating environment variables in mac, Older version 3.6.2.2 was not getting reflected in terminal. I followed source ~/.bash_profile as well. Then i decided to explicitly uninstall MVN 3.6.3 and fresh install 3.6.2.2 and it worked. Thanks for steps mentioned above.

Answer (score 9):

On a Mac, try doing

```
brew list mvn
```

If it's listed, it means it was installed using brew, and then you can uninstall it running:

```
brew uninstall mvn
```

Answer (score 0):

on mac os you can remove the symbolic link and then delete directory

`which mvn`

```
/Users/Viraj/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current/bin/mvn
```

`unlink ~/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current/bin/mvn`

feel free to delete the unlinked directory

```
rm -r ~/.sdkman/candidates/maven
```